# What is the regex for Zambian international mobile number?

Tags: regex

Zambia's country code is +260. Zambia has three mobile service providers. Below is a list of the first two digits a Zambian mobile number can have depending on the mobile service provider.

Mobile Service providers:

1. Zamtel: '95', '75'
2. Airtel: '97', '77'
3. MTN: '96', '76'

The length of a Zambian international mobile number is 12 digits. So an example of a correct number would be +260950000000.

I am looking for the regular expression for this mobile number format.

Comment: `\+260[79][567]\d{7}`

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression would work

```
/^\+260(96|76|95|75|97|77)\d{7}$/
```

Comment: No need for repetition. Check Onyambu's comment above. Either way, if you're using the `^` anchor, you should also use the `$` anchor at the end for an exact match. Otherwise, you should probably throw a `\b` at the end.